# CODE optimization over time complexity

Tags: c++

I need to optimize this code as per time complexity. No issues for space complexity. I am looking for a better logic to solve the purpose in minimum time.

the question is
input n and d
n- number of days -a[n] share values at each day
d- number of profits -b[d] values of each profit

output
for every d profit display
1) two values
or
2) -1

1)two value:-    each day the value of shares may or may not change, but if it changes, the increased change in shares must be equal to profit b[d]. print index (starting from 1) of those days where the profit is exactly same as the profit and the difference between the index in minimum.

2) -1 if not possible

for example

```
input
4 2
1 2 3 5
3 8
```

output

```
2 4
-1
```

Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 


int main() {

    double i,j,k,s=100000000,p,q,flag;
    double n,d;
    cin>>n>>d;
    vector<double> a(n);
    vector<double> b(d);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<d;++i){
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    for(k=0;k<d;++k)
    {   flag=9;
      p=q=0;   
     for(i=0;i<n-1;++i){
            for(j=i+1;j<n;++j){
            if((a[j]-a[i])==b[k]){
                if(s>(j-i)){
                    s=j-i;
                    p=i+1;
                    q=j+1;
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }        
      }
        s=100000000;

    if(flag!=9)    
    cout<<p<<" "<<q<<"\n";
    else
    cout<<"-1\n";    
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may store result, instead of recomputing for each benefit:

```
struct Range {
    std::size_t start;
    std::size_t last;
};

int duration(const Range& range)
{
    return range.last - range.start;    
}

bool operator < (const Range& lhs, const Range& rhs)
{
    return duration(lhs) < duration(rhs);
}

std::map<int, Range>
compute_profits(const std::vector<int>& shares){
    std::map<int, Range> res;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != shares.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j != shares.size(); ++j) {
            const auto benefit = shares[j] - shares[i];
            const Range range{i, j};
            auto p = res.emplace(benefit, range);

            if (!p.second) {
                // Already exist, use the better one
                auto it = p.first;
                it->second = std::min(it->second, range);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

void show_result(const std::vector<int>& shares,
                 const std::vector<int>& benefits)
{
    auto profits = compute_profits(shares);

    for (const auto b : benefits) {
        auto it = profits.find(b);

        if (it == profits.end()) {
            std::cout << -1 << std::endl;
        } else {
            const auto& range = it->second;
            std::cout << 1 + range.start << " " << 1 + range.last << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/KvtIfQ)

So complexity is `#days² + #benefits * log(#profits)`

where `#profits` is `#days²`

instead of your solution which is `#days² * #benefits`